# RTI DDS Src HostId to IP Address

Tags: data-distribution-service

I am using *RTI DDS Spy* to debug a DDS application. I have noticed odd messages in the Spy tool that I believe are not coming from my application.

The question is how do I take a `Src HostId` and figure out the IP address of the sender? (Wireshark is not an option.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields in the `Src HostId` are normally a hexadecimal version of the source IP address. For example take the following output of Spy:

```
source_timestamp   Info  Src HostId  topic               type              
-----------------  ----  ----------  ------------------  ------------------  
1369074721.938245  R +N  C0A80103    CellTopic           life::CellType    
1369074721.937270  W +N  C0A80103    CellTopic           life::CellType    
1369074721.938615  D +N  C0A80103    CellTopic           life::CellType    
1369074721.938726  D +N  C0A80103    CellTopic           life::CellType
```

Looking at the four bytes in the third column `C0 A8 01 03`, translating them from hexadecimal into decimal one by one results in `192.168.1.3` (because `C0` is `192` in decimal, `A8` is `168`, and obviously `01` is `1` and `03` is `3`).

By the way, for more details on the `Src HostId`, also check out the help using `rtiddsspy -hOutput`:

```
Src HostId         :   Contains the sourceId part of the Global Unique 
                       IDentifier (GUID) of the writer that sent the sample.
                       This value is formatted as an IP address because this
                       is the default setting for NDDS. Consequently this
                       column will match the IP address of the sender
                       of the message provided that: (1) the application is
                       running on an IP network, (2) it has not disabled the
                       UDPv4 transport and (3) it has not explicitly 
                       overridden the 'appId'
```

Comment: Awesome. I should have realized that. I kept thinking it looked so familiar, but didn't make the connection. And now, I have verified that it was not my message. It was someone else borrowing my domain.

Comment: Ah, that is a common issue. It is always fun to suddenly discover other people messing around on your domain -- or the other way around :-). You can fairly easily avoid such collisions by choosing your port-numbers differently, if you really need to.